# how to optimize the query for graph length in cypher?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

my request is find top 10 length of path in my graph which contained about 90000 nodes and 100000 relationships.

my cypher statement is below:

```
MATCH (a:Acct), (b:Acct) WHERE id(a) <> id(b)
MATCH p=shortestPath((a)-[:TrxTo*]-(b))
RETURN length(p) AS len, extract(x IN nodes(p) | x.acctNo) AS path
ORDER BY len DESC LIMIT 10;
```

it token more than 10 hours running in my laptop without any result, finally i stopped it. i'm using the “neo4j-community-3.4.0-alpha06” .

i think the graph with 100000 nodes is not very large, but how to raise efficiency in the case.

Comment: Doesn't suprise me. You could basically run into doing a shortest path search from every node to every other node so that could result into 90 000 * 90 000 shortest path calls. Also imagine you have one path with 900 hops and this is by far the longest. The next longest path is basically the same path but ending one node earlier.

Comment: so, it is impossible to calculate diatmeter of  the graph and hard to get the key node in whole graph? sometimes i need to find some key node like some contacts in a graph.

Comment: Its not impossible. But I can't recommend you doing it like this. It's just to much work for the DB and the result is not that meaningful. On your right side of the browser there is a star. Click on it go on sample scripts -> data Profiling -> "What kind of nodes exist". You can see neo4j only checks a percentage of all nodes. What you want to do in your query is checking all nodes* all nodes.

Comment: You could ask a new question and explain what you want to know. Things like knowing the longest possible path in a graph are nice to know but you dont actually need it (in most cases). You can check a small percentage of your nodes and be happy with knowing that you found a path about 900 hops and just assume that this is the longest path.

Comment: @Yoshi thanks a lot for your suggestion. And if i wanna get some key nodes below, should i use the rand() for sampling survey?        
        match (a:Acct),(b:Acct) WHERE id(a) <> id(b)
 match p=allShortestPaths((a)-[:TrxTo*]-(b)) with collect(p) as paths,a,b
 match (c:Acct) where all(x in paths where c in nodes(x)) and not c in [a,b]
 return a.acctNo,b.acctNo,c.acctNo as pivotalNode limit 10;

Comment: What is a key node for you? A node with lots of edges?